# error messages not getting correct values from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pjax

So i am trying to display a message but instead it displays the whole page's code. However this only happens when i am registering it does work for logging in. Sorry for the long code, i wanted to include both working and non-working parts.

index.php:

```
<?php define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true); ?>
<?php require('members.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="author" content="Corey Mason">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="fluid960/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="fluid960/grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="fluid960/text.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#open").click(function(){
                    $("#register").fadeIn(500);
                });
                $("#close").click(function(){
                    $("#register").fadeOut(500);
                });
                $("#log").click(function(){
                    username=$("#username").val();
                    password=$("#password").val();
                    submit=$("#log").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "",
                        data: "submit="+submit+"&username="+username+"&password="+password,
                        success: function(response) {
                            if(response=='success') {

                            }
                            else {
                                $("#error-log").remove();
                                var error_msg = response;
                                $("#s-log").append('<div id="error-log" class="err welcome dismissible">'+error_msg+'</div>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                $("#reg").click(function(){
                    username=$("#username").val();
                    email=$("#email").val();
                    submit=$("#reg").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "",
                        data: "submit="+submit+"&username="+username+"&email="+email,
                        success: function(response) {
                            if(response==true) {
                                //display notification on login form
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#error-reg").remove();
                                var error_msg = response;
                                $("#s-reg").append('<div id="error-reg" class="err welcome dismissible">'+error_msg+'</div>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pjax">
            <div class="sign-box">
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="main container_16 clearfix">
                        <form action="index.php">
                            <div id="s-log" class="section">
                                <div class="welcome dismissible"> <!-- make dismissible javascript -->
                                    <strong>Welcome.</strong> Please enter your details to login.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <fieldset class="label_side top">
                                <label for="username">Username<span>or email address</span></label>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset class="label_side bottom">
                                <label for="password">Password<span><a href="#">Do you remember?</a></span></label>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <div class="button_bar clearfix">
                                <button id="log" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                                    <span>Login</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <button id="open" class="right" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <span>Not Registered ?</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="register" class="register-box" style="display:none;">
                <form action="index.php">
                    <div id="s-reg" class="section">
                    </div>
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                    <div class="columns clearfix">
                        <div class="col_50">
                            <fieldset class="label_top top">
                                <label for="username">Username<span>Between 5 and 20 characters</span></label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col_50">
                            <fieldset class="label_top top right">
                                <label for="">Name<span>so we know who you are</span></label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text"> <!-- to do -->
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="columns clearfix">
                        <div class="col_50">
                            <fieldset class="label_top">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col_50">
                            <fieldset class="label_top right">
                                <label for="">Repeat Email</label>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text"> <!-- to do -->
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <fieldset class="label_side bottom">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <label>A password will be e-mailed to you, this may be changed later.</label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <!-- edit -->
                    <div class="button_bar clearfix">
                        <button id="reg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
                            <span>Register</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" id="close" class="right">
                            <span>Cancel</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

members.php

```
<?php if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) header("Location: ../index.php"); ?>
<?php

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('Login');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 1 week

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['FRCteam3482Remember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the FRCteam3482Remember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: ../../index.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('FRCteam3482Remember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err) {
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        // Save the error messages in the session

        echo $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
        //php unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
        //header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else {
        echo 'success';
        //header("Location: workspace/index.php");
    }
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Your username contains invalid characters!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Your email is not valid!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Generate a random password

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        // Escape the input data


        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'FRC Team 3482',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'FRC Team 3482 - Your Password',
                        'Your password is: '.$pass);

            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your password!';
            echo 'success';
        }
        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        echo $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
    }

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // Nothing?
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors are in your log files?

Comment: sorry if the title was misleading, there are no php errors but the "error message" for the registration system i'm making is not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to kill members.php after it outputs the errors for your JS:

```
if(count($err))
{
    $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    echo $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'];
    die;
}
```

Right now it's displaying the errors and the result of the redirection to index.php that happens right after.